# Header overlapping text

Tags: css, html, header

My header is clipping the top portion of the page and often this leads to text overlapping and clipping, especially when using a direct link halfway down the page.

An example of this is when you click the link to view comments for a particular Wordpress blog post:

http://blog.diginomics.com/bitcoins-innate-regulation/#comments

Is there something I can put into my CSS that will create a type of buffer zone or make it some the rest of the page recognizes where the header ends?

How else can I solve this to retain responsive design?
Here is the CSS code for my header:

```
.header{
width:auto;
height: auto;
font-size:60px;
font-weight: 400;
text-align: center;
margin:0 auto;
padding-top:0;
```

}
I tried adding a margin-bottom of 20px but nothing happened. Are you suggesting to add a margin-top to the main page section?

Comment: Try adding a margin-top, it should work.

Comment: You should provide us with some sample code for us to be able to help you.